# Sort users by score. Numbers being rendered instead of names

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

[image]

The database column for my users' names is `first_name`. Score is not a column in the guides database.

In my karma controller:

```
  def hiscores
    @users = User.all.map(&:guides).flatten.map(&:score).sort
  end
```

In hiscores.html.erb

```
<h1>Karma Hiscores</h1>
<blockquote>Users sorted by most karma</blockquote>


<ul>
  <% @users.each do |user| %>
  <li><%= user %></li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

**EDITS**

Guide model

```
class Guide < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :link, uniqueness: true
  validates :link, presence: true
  validates :title, presence: true 

  belongs_to :user
  has_many :comments


  acts_as_taggable
  acts_as_votable

  def to_param
    "#{id} #{title}".parameterize
  end

  def score
    upvotes.count - downvotes.count
  end


end


User.rb

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, #:recoverable,
          :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  validates :first_name, presence: true
  validates :email, presence: true
  validates :email, uniqueness: true
  validates :runescape_username, presence: true

  has_many :guides
  has_many :comments

  acts_as_voter





end
```

Here is what my karma controller looks like now:

```
class KarmaController < ApplicationController
  def hiscores
    @users =  (guides.upvote.count - guides.downvote.count).desc
  end
end
```

Comment: Your `@users` doesn't contain what you think it contains. Use ActiveRecord to pull users in the correct order by score, not `User.all` followed by a series of maps, it's bad practice.

Comment: Score isn't in the user table, though. Will that still work? If so, how would I do it?

Comment: Sure, you may have to use `joins` so as not to have N+1 queries. See the [Rails Guide to ActiveRecord Queries](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#joining-tables). You need to edit your question and show your models for more specific help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**In your karma controller:**

```
def hiscores
  @users = User.all.sort{ |x, y| y.user_score <=> x.user_score }
end
```

**In your User.rb:**

If each user has_many: guides, then

```
def user_score
  self.guides.inject(0) { |sum, guide| sum += guide.score }
end
```

Else if each user has_one: guide, then

```
def user_score
  self.guide.score
end
```

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this:

```
@users = User.find(:all, include: [:guides], order: "(guides.upvotes.count - guides.downvotes.count) desc")
```

I am not sure if include is required, I am typing from the top of my head :)

**Edit:**

You should try to use [Caching](https://github.com/ryanto/acts_as_votable#caching) from `acts_as_votable`.

This would give you fields such as `cached_votes_up` and `cached_votes_down` and `cached_votes_score`.

Then you could query users as

```
@users = User.find(:all, include: [:guides], order: "guides.cached_votes_score desc")
```

Comment: @DylanRichards - sorry, it should be `order`. Have updated the answer.

Comment: `SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: guides.score`

I probably should have mentioned that score isn't a column in the guides database.

Comment: Hmm - yeah I was assuming that. Could you share your models in that case? And also what exactly is `score`?

Comment: Updated the original post.

Comment: ok in that case - would you be able to use `order: "(guides.upvotes.count - guides.downvotes.count) desc"`

Comment: Oh, I see. Give me a second.

Comment: Getting `/app/controllers/karma_controller.rb:3: syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting keyword_end` - But an end is there. I updated my original post.

Comment: Fixed that. Now getting

Comment: `undefined local variable or method `guides' for #<KarmaController:0x00000108812028>` @Srikanth

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44472/discussion-between-srikanth-venugopalan-and-dylan-richards)

Comment: `SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: guides.downvotes.count: SELECT "users"."id" AS t0_r0, "users"."first_name" AS t0_r1`